# Deleted files accidentally in SourceTree, need help to recover

Tags: git, file, atlassian-sourcetree

So I was trying to learn how to use SourceTree and then I got to a point where I had 2 repositories (with different names) for the same project, so I decided to delete one of those repositories to get a cleaner interface. Then it deleted the whole project from my computer, is it possible to recover the files?

By the way, I was trying to "upload" the project to a repository on BitBucket, but I was unable to do so, the project isn't stored anywhere else.

Answer (score 5):

If the files were inside a git repo and the repository still exists you can recover them by doing a checkout on a previous commit when the files existed.

In source tree you can simply double click a previous commit, presuming you still have the repo on disk.

Comment: But how can I search in which commit I deleted it? Our repo is used by tens of persons :)

Answer (score 0):

Deleted files in SourceTree can be easily recovered by doing the following:

1. Right-click the commit that deleted the files and select **Reverse commit...** from the context menu.
2. Click **File Status** under **Workspace**.
3. Select all files except for the ones you want to recover, right-click the selected files and click **Discard** from the context menu.
4. Make sure the files you want to recover are checked, click the **Commit** button to commit them.
5. Finally click the **Push** button to push the commit that recovers the deleted files to the GIT repository.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

Just double click the previous commit. You will have the deleted files in folder. Restore the files via copy-paste. That's all.